# Git merging two local branches and pushing one of that local branch to upstream remote 'origin' branch

Tags: java, git

I am having an issue of my git HEAD going backwards by certain days length when I do the following

1. Complete my changes in my **Sprint1.4Branc**h and add all files, then commit my files to local branch of Sprint1.4Branch (`$git commit -m "message"`)
2. Then check out to "**LifeGoals**" local branch(`$ git checkout LifeGoals`). **LifeGoals** is the branch(created by cloning from the git repository) from which I created my local **Sprint1.4Branch** to do my sprint specific user story coding.
3. Merge Sprint1.4Branch in to local LifeGoals ( `$ git merge Sprint1.4Branch`)
4. Push local LifeGoals branch to remote 'origin' (`$git push origin LifeGoals`) **Note**: Only **LifeGoals** has upstream connection to remote **origin**. *Sprint1.4Branch* is purely local branch alone.
5. Check out to local branch of 'Sprint1.4Branch' to get back in to local branch to make further changes. (`$git checkout Sprint1.4Branch`)
   I see that some of the files in my IDE are moved to a status which is few days back wards.

   What is the mistake I am doing ?
   ***At least I have my commits to go back to, I believe.***

Comment: It is not really clear what you say is wrong in step 5. Are you saying that the files in `Sprint1.4Branch` at Step 5 are different/older from the state they were in Step 1? Or are you saying that you expected the `Sprint1.4Branch` branch to somehow have been updated by the steps 2, 3, 4 or 5 and they were not?

Comment: @Mort Yes. You are right on the spot. that is what I am saying at step 5 is that, when I get back in to my Sprint1.4Branch after I merged it in to LifeGoals, I see the files are reverted to some few days back stage. Some of the latest addition of methods, change of method logic disappeared.

Comment: It is still not clear what you are saying. Are you saying that at Step 5, `Sprint1.4Branch` is different than it was after step1 ? (are you sure?) It seems more likely that `Sprint1.4Branch` is different from the `LifeGoals` branch which is totally expected. Please be very explicit about exactly what you expect to be equal, and what you see as different.

Comment: @Mort I think, I made it clear in my previous comment. Since my previous push which I did exactly like this time, I implemented further development by enhancing certain classes, config, properties files, which are all added to the git, and committed. Then as you can see from my above 5 steps, I merged that changes in the **Sprint 1.4Branch** in to the **LifeGoals** branch. But when I came back to my working branch **Sprint1.4Branch**, I had expected the same state when I went about merging in to LifeGoals. NOTE: I did not call git pull before push , because I am only the person working on it.

Comment: Please be specific. Please just write exactly this sentence and nothing more if it is true. "The files in my local Sprint1.4Branch after Step1 were different from the files in my local Sprint1.4Branch  after Step5"

Comment: @Mort It is true. Yes.

Comment: @Mort It is true. Yes.
I will elaborate on files being **different**.  The progress I made on cerain class files, config files have been rolled back. To what back date, I can't say, specific date. My hunch is about the time I merged previous time.